# multiple appdomain in single process

Tags: c#

Hi everyone I want to ask all of you one question related to application domain.

In .Net appdomain acts as a security boundary and two applications can run in two different domains within same process, but when i try to run multiple instances of an exe it shows in different processes in task manager.

Why is it so?

Why does it not show in same process with different appdomains?

Also is there is a way to do this i.e. multiple windows application in different appdomain inside same process.

Answer (score 3):

Appdomain is a feature of the .NET framework. When you run exe's in Windows, they are started as separate processes, no matter what they are, the Windows loader doesn't care.

Theoretically, you can run any number of apps in the same appdomain, but why would you want that, if you don't need its benefits?