# AppDomain: Multiple AppDomain, limitations, stackoverflow

Tags: c#, appdomain

As I was searching it states that a [single process can have multiple app domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540712/multiple-appdomain-in-single-process) but how many is multiple? Can it be thousands or more than that?

Comment: _"I have two questions"_ - then also post 2 questions.

Comment: "it will totally unload main appdomain" This is because Hans's answer calls `Environment.Exit(-1);`. If you skip that call, your app will not get unloaded.